# Learning iOS MapKit - multiple pins on map from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, mapkit

Attempting to take a NSSDictionary that contains all my locations, titles, and subtitles and enumerate through them and add them to my mapView.The first part seems fine; I read the Plist and can access the various parts. What I'm having problems with is running through the enumeration.

The NSLog asking for the title correctly reports that property to the console.

In the end,though, I see no pins. In addition, after the NSLog call:

```
NSLog(@"My %i annotations are: %@", self.mapView.annotations.count, self.mapView.annotations);
```

I get in response:

```
"My 1 annotations are: (
    "<MKPointAnnotation: 0xd0151f0>" )
```

Which appears to be just **one** memory location for **one** annotation. *Sigh*.

I'm sure I'm doing something simple and wrong, but would appreciate any help. I've been searching all day, and seen some things that appear to be answers here, but not anything that helps me in this particular construction.

Thanks you in advance.

The following code is fired off in the main viewController, the first method seen is called at the end of ViewDidLoad.

```
-(void) loadUpLocations{

NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *errorDesc=nil;

//make path to plist in bundle
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"locations2" ofType:@"plist"];
//fill data object with contents of file
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
myLocations=[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:myData 
                                             mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves 
                                                       format:&format
                                             errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (!myLocations) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading Plist: %@ format: %@", errorDesc,format);
}

myAnnotation=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];

for (NSString *loc in myLocations) {
    NSDictionary *value =[myLocations objectForKey:loc];

    //NSLog(@"Loc is equal to: %@",loc);

    //loop through and make annotations

    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                      [[value objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue],
                                      [[value objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
    myAnnotation.title = [value objectForKey:@"title"];
    myAnnotation.subtitle = [value objectForKey:@"subtitle"];

    NSLog(@"%@",myAnnotation.title);
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

}

NSLog(@"My %i annotations are: %@", self.mapView.annotations.count, self.mapView.annotations);
}

- (IBAction)zoomToLocation:(id)sender {


//set center for zoom
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.75070416856952, -84.37034368515015);;

//set level of zoom
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=.03;
span.longitudeDelta=.03;
region.span=span;


[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

// This gets called every time an annotation is in the map view

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation{
NSLog(@"in annotationsView");


MKPinAnnotationView *myPins=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                 initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                 reuseIdentifier:@"myPins"];
myPins.animatesDrop=YES;
return myPins;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
myAnnotation=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
```

is currently outside the `for` loop that creates the annotations so only one object ever gets instantiated and you keep modifying that one instance.

Move that line to inside the `for` loop (eg. above the line that sets the coordinate).

Also, if you are not using ARC, add a `[myAnnotation release];` after the `addAnnotation` line.

Comment: Yeah, am using ARC. 

I kept getting an error when I put the initialization in the loop. It complained about the instance being released prematurely.

I'll try again, and report back with the actual error. 

Thank for looking.

Comment: Here's the error:  An instance 0x6d2f2f0 of class MKPointAnnotation was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x6d2dba0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x6d2d9e0: Observer: 0x7c04f70, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x6d2d5e0>

Comment: That's a separate issue.  That error can happen when the latitude or longitude values are invalid.  After setting myAnnotation.coordinate, log it using `NSLog(@"lat = %f, long = %f", myAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, myAnnotation.coordinate.longitude);`.  Make sure the latitudes are between -90 and 90 and that the longitudes are between -180 and 180.

Comment: The numbers seem ok. One weird thing is that there are 6 locations, but the NSLog at the end only reports 5 Annotations.

Comment: That led me to the right answer. My Plist had latitude and longitude reversed. Let that be a lesson to us all. Thanks.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina you just saved my life!